# trouble with jQuery animation JsFiddle Link -> jsfiddle.net/QYry5

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

I have written some code which is working fine but this animation works only first time and then it just loads and displays (no animation)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.moreInfo").hide();

    $("a").mouseover(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        t.parent().next().eq(0).show();
        t.parent().next().animate({ width: '300px' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
    });

    $("a").mouseleave(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        $(this).parent().next().hide(500);
    });
});
```

HTML is here :

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
        <li class="moreInfo">More Info</li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
        <li class="moreInfo">Second More Info</li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
        <li class="moreInfo">More Info</li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
        <li class="moreInfo">Second More Info</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On item is mouseover, It gives effects (easeOutBounce & slowly moving) for the first time but when I repeat the same for second time, it neither show slow moving nor easeOutBounce effect. It just loads and that too very fast. I think it might be caching but i dont know how to avoid it.

Can you guys please help me out to resolve this issue ?

Update : I have posted HTML Code also JsFiddle Link -> http://jsfiddle.net/QYry5

Comment: please post a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see your code in action.

Comment: The first time it animates to 300 pixels. The next time it is already at 300 pixels so there's nothing to animate.

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Thats the stupidest comment ive read here in a while. Its just good practice to provide the markup *and* code, or a jsfiddle. Kudos for *guessing* the solution to this problem, but more often than not, without a working (or broken) example, its impossible to answer properly. **Edit** and now youve deleted your guesswork answer (And the comment telling the OP Not to post a jsfiddle :|) - no doubt because you have no idea if it fixes the problem.

Comment: ok ok ok - I get it.... :|

Comment: If posting a jsfiddle is tricky, at least post a section of the HTML. This will also help you get an answer.

Comment: jsFiddle makes for a great demo and I think every question should include one. HOWEVER, a jsFiddle should not be a substitute for posting the code, making the question fully "self-contained" and helpful to others long after jsFiddle link expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed in JS & CSS:

JS:

```
t.parent().next().eq(0).show(2000,'easeOutBounce');
```

CSS:

```
.moreInfo
        {
            display:block;
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 1px solid Yellow;
            width:300px;                
        }
```

here is the updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QYry5/1/

Problem was with width only. After first animation it acquires 300px width so there was no more scope for the animation second time. If you want to play only on width you should reset the width on mouseleave event.

on mouseover:

```
t.parent().next().animate({ width: '+=300px' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

on mouseleve:

`t.parent().next().animate({ width: '-=300px' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce',function(){$(this).hide()})`;

here is the updated jsFiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QYry5/2/

Comment: @jasper: I have edited my answer accordingly. Hope this will help.